# Move a column up-/downwards

Tags: macro

I was wondering if, out of the box, one can move an entire column up- and downwards.

Say, we have the following text:

```
1 a
    b
      c
2 d
    e
      f
```

My goal is to convert this into

```
1 a b c


2 d e f
```

This does not seem possible via [visual block operations](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/visual.html#blockwise-operators), since we need to *operate* on the column in the context of the rows above and below. In my case, I would need to *overwrite* the (empty) row values above the selected column.

Or do we need to resort to writing macros to accomplish this?

In the last case, I was thinking of a macro in the line of

```
1. <detect the first non-whitespace character> 
2. <delete up to the last non-whitespace character> 
3. <move up a row via insertion mode> 
4. <append the row with the deleted characters from the previous row>
```

This can be applied consequtively for each column in the format given above. Only, I'm not sure how to do step (1) and (2) yet. :)

Comment: I don't think vim can do this out of the box. There's [a plugin](https://github.com/gavinbeatty/dragvisuals.vim) that was developed for this purpose, but it's not maintained anymore and has some issues.

Comment: https://github.com/zirrostig/vim-schlepp is another plugin

Comment: Honestly in this case I would just spam join (`J`)

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Coud you elaborate?

Comment: @Mass vim-schlepp seems very promising, I'll have a look. :)

Comment: @D.BenKnoble I don't think there is any other way. Or at least I think `3Jj3J` would be the best way to do what the OP wants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use visual block mode if you are careful about the boundaries.

First, type `:set ve=all` to turn on virtual edit mode.  Then on the b, press ctrl-v to enter block visual mode, and type G to put the range to the bottom.  Press y to yank this region.

```
1 a
    [b]
    [ ] c
2 d [ ]
    [e]
    [ ] f
```

Now, type k to go up one character.  Since we're in virtual edit mode, the cursor goes to what is empty space.  Press 1v which means re-enter visual block mode with the same width and height as the last operation.  Press p to put.  This overwrites the text without changing anything else.

```
1 a [b]
    [ ]
    [ ] c
2 d [e]
    [ ]
        f
```

Go to the c and type ctrl-v G y kk 1v p, similar to before

```
1 a b           1 a b [c] 
                      [ ] 
      [c]             [ ] 
2 d e [ ]  ->   2 d e [f] 
      [ ]              
      [f]              f
```

Note, this leaves an f which you can either delete afterwards or you could have originally extended your buffer a few blank lines down to grab extra whitespace to replace the f with.

To turn off virtual edit afterwards, use `:set ve=` or `:set ve=block`.

Comment: What kind of motion  is `G`? I can not find it in the [documentation](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/motion.html).

Comment: `:help G` or search `*G*` in that document link.  goes to the last line

Comment: The procedure works as a charm. :) How does `1v` work? What does the `1` stand for?

Comment: the `1v` stands for 'select the same number of characters or region as the previous visual operation' .. `2v` would be select twice that.  or quadruple, in block mode since in block mode both width and height are multipled

Answer (score 1):

From vim helpdocs:

```
J           Join [count] lines, with a minimum of two lines.
            Remove the indent and insert up to two spaces (see
            below).  Fails when on the last line of the buffer.
            If [count] is too big it is reduce to the number of
            lines available.
```

For your specific purpose, I myself would prefer `3Jj3J`, but you can do same with visual selection.

First visually select these first 3 lines.

```
1 a
    b
      c
```

Then, press `J`.

Then do the same for the next 3 lines.